# Dropwizard not displaying validation response in Json

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard, hibernate-validator

I have enabled validation in DropWizard using the `@Valid` on the bean and the other annotation from `javax.validation.constraints` packages. Validation works fine but the `JSON` response does not have the Error entity holding the validation error message. The json which i get is

```
{"code":400,"message":"Unable to process JSON"}
```

Can you please let me know what changes need to be made to enable the validation failure response with the Error entity.
The dropwizard version that i am using is `0.8`. I read somewhere to set the `ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE` to get the error entity but that is also not working.

Comment: Add more relevant code, especially for validated bean, service, etc.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of your bean and it's usage ?